# Jquery autocomplete keyboard navigation set the Value in input, how to change field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, autocomplete, keyboard-events

This is my code of a very simple autocomplete

```
var club_ajax_success = function (data) {
  $("input#sm_autosearch_clubteam").autocomplete({
    source: data,
    select: club_autocomplete_select
  });
  $('input#sm_autosearch_clubteam').prop('disabled', '').prop('placeholder', 'Zoek een club');
};
```

this is the structure of one single record of my autocomplete store

- *entirelabel* => "Club Goeree Overflakkee"
- *entirelabel_filtered* => "Club Goeree Overflakkee"
- *label* => "Goeree Overflakkee"
- *label_filtered* => "Goeree Overflakkee"
- *value* => "XYZ123"

if i use my keyboard arrows to navigate in the dropdown, displayed after i start to type on my `<input>`, the effect is that in the input type is shown the *value* of the record, but I would like the autocomplete to display the *label*, or at least i would like to remove the possibility to navigate with arrows.

some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's the solution

```
$("input#sm_autosearch_clubteam").autocomplete({
  source: improvedSearchData,
  select: club_autocomplete_select,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $('input#sm_autosearch_clubteam').val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  }
});
```